# Could you please give an example for this regular expression for me?

Tags: java, regex

The regular expression is  `(\\w+).*>(.{23}) ([^\\[]+)\\[([^\\]]+)]: (.+)`

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+).*>(.{23}) ([^\\[]+)\\[([^\\]]+)]: (.+)")
String s = "xxxxxx";   //this is what I want
Matcher matcher =  pattern.matcher(s);
System.out.println(matcher.find());   // I hope "true"
```

Maybe it's not suited to ask for help here. But I am not expert in regular expression and I need to know the result quickly.

I reduced the complexity and tried some schemes .

- `abbb>(ccccccccccccccccccccddddddddddcc)`   is OK to `(\\w+).*>(.{23})`
- `(\\a)`                                     is OK to `([^\\[]+)`

but if I combine them.

`abbb>(ccccccccccccccccccccddddddddddcc) (\\a)`  is not OK to `(\\w+).*>(.{23}) ([^\\[]+)`

So I am confused, especially the  `([^\\[]+)\\[([^\\]]+)]: (.+)`   part.
Thanks .

Comment: Could you please explain what do you want to achieve using regular expression? Your examples are interesting but do not help to understand what do you need.

Comment: Also, please mention where you want to use the regex. There are many different regex dialects, so the meaning of a regex differs depending on which software you use it with.#

Comment: For Java, I recommend you to use this online tester: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: sorry,just now I didn't make the problem clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very unclear, but if you needed strings to match your regular expression, I made some for you:

```
matches:true, string:word-0>kiOgNnuGfalhTfkqxtsCyhN f[RxQrH]: tqtmY
matches:true, string:word-1>wlnJomNExhCLHjrmsyLsKhh g[fXSsPYD]: BbzUM
matches:true, string:word-2>pdTepooJdeDgnODUAJMMPtB Pf[d]: aqmYx
matches:true, string:word-3>jMNDTuvCBufSEAxuzPDmyFG xt[T[RJjQEpJ]: bdlLS
matches:true, string:word-4>kHwqbjwNrSqhGeutzxtqiEy f[SmjJVt]: dWwlU
matches:true, string:word-5>UreUxUwpIyHqPXqVlALIlmr vuJScq[QFIpLCplW]: UuL0K
matches:true, string:word-6>dojPDeXqAfsHvGjOfvyZOtR aq[ImRqDn]: eyqlr
matches:true, string:word-7>ViljtcHRPzMjktFzqwDcprB le[U]: yfohG
matches:true, string:word-8>sjtQoCTupFbYqzhxcnrPbMh hhR[gufba]: DmREu
matches:true, string:word-9>ZauFhTHuvuXcqlymybjYHzj yv[FAaupu]: ZtrqL
```

all of them match `"(\\w+).*>(.{23}) ([^\\[]+)\\[([^\\]]+)]: (.+)"` and that list was generated by some code i wrote up real quick:

```
// generate some strings....
for (String string : full) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+).*>(.{23}) ([^\\[]+)\\[([^\\]]+)]: (.+)");
    Matcher matcher =  pattern.matcher(string);
    System.out.println("matches:" + matcher.find() + ", string:" + string);
}
```

Comment: How did you get **full** list?

Comment: it was composed by some of my own code, I used some random character generators and http://code.google.com/p/xeger/, I split the expression up into 5 parts and generated each one individually to concatenate them together. I did not post the code because of external dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

```
([^\[]+) is what ever exept '[' one or more times
\[([^\]]+)]: (\.+) '[' what ever except ']' one or more times ']' : a space and
one ore more dots
```

an example that matches this is 'oo[pp]: ...'

The parenthesis represents groups.

Comment: but  **oo[pp]... **  cannot work with **([^\\[]+)\\[([^\\]]+)]: (.+)**  according to my test

Comment: If you did not figured out yet.. go here myregexp.com . For regex write [^\[]+\[[^\]]+\]: .+ this is your regex without grouping, and down write 'oo[pp]: ...' you will see that it matches